# Java - Adding Rows is there a more efficient way?

Tags: java, row

Below is the code, I am just wondering if others are coding it differently. Maybe I can make small changes. Thanks in advance!

```
public class addRow {

    public static int[][] insert(int [][] a, int [] row, int index){

        int [][] x = new int[a.length+1][a.length];
        int [] temp;

        for(int i=0; i<x.length-1; i++)
        {
            x[i] = a[i];

            if(i == index)
            {
                temp = a[i];
                x[i] = row;
                x[i+1] = temp;          
            }           
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] a = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{10,11,12}};
        int[] row = {7,8,9};

        int [][] b = insert(a,row ,2);


        for(int r=0; r < b.length; r++){
            for(int c=0;c< b[r].length; c++){
                System.out.print(b[r][c] + " ");
            }System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.arraycopy` is your answer.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29

It uses native code to copy arrays in memory directly, making it much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop doesn't do what you think it does. When you swap rows `i` and `i+1` in `x`, the next iteration of the loop will overwrite the element you put in `x[i+1]` on the previous iteration. You need to keep an extra index (or split your loop) to keep track of the difference in positions between `a` and `x` after hitting `index`. A better approach, though, is to use `System.arraycopy`.

Also, there's no reason to allocate space for the rows of `x` in its initializer, since you are assigning elements of `a` (or `row`) to them anyway. My version of your method is:

```
public static int[][] insert(int [][] a, int [] row, int index){
    int[][] x = new int[a.length + 1][]; // no second dimension
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, x, 0, index);
    x[index] = row;
    System.arraycopy(a, index, x, index + 1, a.length - index);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh I am glad I asked, wasnt very sure so I wanted to know about a different way of doing it. I will now trace it with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Just because your code seems to be working for `1` case, it doesn't mean it proper. You'd have tried out the other cases as well.

You need to make the following changes in your method for it to work properly.

```
public static int[][] insert(int [][] a, int [] row, int index){

    int [][] x = new int[a.length+1][a.length];
    int j = 0; // New counter for array `a`
    // Also `temp` array removed. Not required at all.
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i] = a[j];
        if (i == index) {
            x[i] = row;
            x[i + 1] = a[j];
        } else {
            j++;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

This is the maximum you can optimize your code as such, without changing the base of your code.

Now regarding optimizing it **big time**, as others suggested, you could use the [`System#arrayCopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).